# Website traffic suddenly down, banned by google after adding around 700 products

Tags: google, traffic, search-results

I have a ecommerce website, phone accesories retail. In the first three months the google traffic risend natural and good up to 200 visitors per day (google search). 
At the begging of june, in a single day, i have added around 700 products. In the next days the google organic traffic dropped down dramatically. As seen in the webmaster tools screenshot:

[image: webmaster tools]

The description of new products was copy paste from supplier website with very little editing.

After the dropdown i tried to clean the website of duplicate products. I have for the same product, different colors with diferent urls and same content. I've added canonical to point to one product for each set of colors.

Adding those products slowed my website very much so i have changed my server to a VPS, and optimised the website speed. I thought to eliminate all reasons for witch website is down.

The number of indexed pages in serp rised, but my organic traffic dropped.

A few days before the drop i have added Structured Data markup for the page product. I removed the code around 24 june.

[image: structured data]

At this moment i have two solutions:

1. To put a noindex meta for the new products added.
2. To delete all products and not sell them any more. The margin is low for this products any way.

What could be a reason for the drop and what should i do so my website regain it's google trust and reappear in SERPs?

The website is: http://mobyl.ro

Comment: I think my problem is a common one for ecommerce websites that add products everyday and could get hit by a drop in traffic. We, as ecommerce webmasters face the problem that we have duplicate descriptions and titles. You cannot create unique and descriptions for 400 phone cases (for example), or batteries or chargers. I am interested in the possible reasons, and ways to investigate further myself. In the SEO world nothing is long term general and we learn from examples.

Comment: Another example could apply in my case. Matt Cutts said in a video around one year ago: Google may just ignore the duplicate content, “I wouldn’t stress about this unless the content that you have duplicated is spammy or keyword stuffing.”  I think i qualify for this case, of duplicate content, but not spammy . But why did my whole website dropped down and not only those pages with duplicate content? Therefore, i would like other opinions.

Comment: That is why i explained my problem in the title also. So this thread to be easy to find by people with the same issue. Regards.